# Animating object affects other objects

Tags: text-object

[image]

I’m trying to do a very simple text animation, making letters move in 2D. So in this example, I want to move the letter ”p”. So I click ”p” and then press i, move it into another position and: all the other letters are stacked on top of each other! I'm on on Blender 2.78

Blender 2.78
Windows 10
computer: Aspire A315-54K
x64-based PC
Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-6300U CPU @ 2.40GHz, 2496 Mhz, 2 kernels

Comment: hello, could you please show some pictures or even share your file? https://pasteall.org/blend/

Comment: did you ever make a simple animation? please tell us your "grade of experience" because otherwise you get an answer which you might not understand.

Answer (score 0):

1. make all objects selectable again...(would be nice if they were selectable when you upload your file so we can work with it and don't have to make everything selectable first. You are searching for an answer so you should make it easy for us to help...)
2. open panel "nonlinear animation"
3. right click on the left panel and delete empty animation data
4. select the object you want to animate
5. Hit <kbd>I</kbd> to insert keyframe -> location
6. move to another frame
7. move your object
8. Hit <kbd>I</kbd> to insert keyframe -> location
9. run animation -> works

[image]

Comment: Sorry about the unconvenience. Well, I go to the NLA, but there is nothing there. And I can't choose anything by right- or left clicking. Do note that I am in 2.78

Comment: that's why i asked...how much experience do you have? you wrote: i tried it in 2.93 -> so try my solution in 2.93

Comment: Sorry. My experience is slight I'm afraid. Your solution works is 2.93 just as you say. But I really like to work in 2.78. :-(

Comment: i am sorry, but my experience in 2.78 is zero....i cannot help you there. I even don't have that version....but PLEASE update your question to make it clear that you want a solution for 2.78. So nobody else has to waste his time for nothing....

Comment: It does say 2.78 in the specs. But thanks a lot for taking your time!

Comment: Yeah…after you edited it was clear, that’s right. Don’t expect any help from me anymore…good luck for finding other helpers who read this and know now how you behave!

Comment: And everybody else can see how thankful you are by hardly checking any answer as right answer. That’s how you are!